# Mocking a while statment Python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

Im pretty new at mocking in Python. I searched pretty deeply for any post that answered this question, but i failed to do so. I want to mock a function that is called within a `while` statement. Is there anyway to do this?

```
def some_function(self, some_param):

    some_counter = 0
    while self.func_i_want_to_mock(mock_param, mock_param2) is False:
        some_counter += 1

    return some_counter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to mock a function that is called within a while statement

Define a side effect function if you want to play with the parameters

```
def func_tbm_side_effect(first, second):
    return 'whatever'
```

Now with the testing

```
import unittest
import mock
import ClassWithSomeFunc

class TestClassWithSomeFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_some_function(self):
        with mock.patch.object(ClassWithSomeFunc, 'some_function') as mocked_sf:
            mocked_sf.side_effect = func_tbm_side_effect
            item = ClassWithSomeFunc()
            value = item.some_function('parameter')
            self.assertEqual(value, 'endless loop')
```

Comment: I see, where I was making my mistake, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
def some_function(self, some_param):

    some_counter = 0
    while self.func_i_want_to_mock(mock_param, mock_param) is False:
        some_counter += 1

    return some_counter



def func_i_want_to_mock(mock_param, mock_param):
    if mock_param1 == x and mock_param2 == y:
       return True
   elif """ ...  all cases"""
```